# Is there a way to change animation speed?

Tags: ios, ios-animations, hero

In iOS swift I use [HeroTransition](https://github.com/HeroTransitions) library to make animations. Is there a way to change animation speed?

```
let vc = DODViewController.init(with: project , projectType: .doodle, needToMapFolderIndex: nil)
            
let heroId = "newcontentscanvas1"
cell.hero.id = heroId
vc.hero.isEnabled = true
vc.view.hero.id = heroId
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a modifier to the hero component. In your case, it can be done as follows,

```
cell.hero.modifiers = [.duration(0.8)]
```

for more info check the following issues on the repo
[#464](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero/issues/464)